# Using Lombok library, but how to customize/override the setter method

Tags: java, lombok

I use lombok library in my java project.

```
@Data
public class Score {
   private long grade;
}
```

With this code, I have getter and setter automatically. e.g.

```
Score score = new Score();
score.setGrade(10);
// when I call score.getGrade(), I get 10.
```

But now I want to customize the setter method to introduce additional logics for the grade value. e.g.

```
public void setGrade(long grade) {
       // so the returned value from getter is always 1 bigger than what has been set.
       this.grade += 1; 
   }
```

Basically, I want to have `score.setGrade(10)` but `score.getGrade()` returns 11. That's override the setter. 
How to achieve it with lombok in use?

Comment: You can just define this method in the class, Lombok will use that then.

Comment: No need to have `@override` annotation? Could you please post an example?

Comment: You've got a good answer, the linked question has some additional related info. Concerning customization: You can't modify what Lombok setter does (e.g., notify observers or alike). All you can do is to stop Lombok from generating the setter and write your own.

Comment: I would suggest you go with the lombok provided setter and getter, and add a new method: getAdjustedScore() that returns the score + 1.  It is a bad idea to override the basic concepts of a setter and getter - it is expected that the value passed to a setter is what gets set and returned for that specific value.  Adding getAdjustedScore() makes it very easy to identify what value you are referring to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just write the getter method in the class. Lombok will not override methods. If a method that it should generate is already present, it will skip that one.

So you could do this:

```java
@Data
public class Score {
  private long grade;

  public void setGrade(long grade) {
    this.grade = grade + 1;
  }
}
```

Or instead just override the getter:

```java
@Data
public class Score {
  private long grade;

  public long getGrade() {
    return this.grade + 1;
  }
}
```

Edit:
To add on your comment: `@Override` is only required if you override methods from superclasses or interfaces. Lombok injects the method directly into your class, thus no `@Override` is required (and it will cause an compiler error, because there is nothing that could be overridden).

Comment: What if I want to pass additional external parameter to the method, is that fine?

Comment: @Leem that will result in the automatically generated setter with only one argument along the one with the one you declared.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyDataClass object = new MyDataClass();
        object.setOverriddenSet("some value");
        if (!"fixed value".equals(object.getOverriddenSet())) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        System.out.println("all went well.");
    }
}

@Data
class MyDataClass {
    String overriddenSet = "fixed initial value";

    void setOverriddenSet(String setTo) {
        overriddenSet = "fixed value";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very confusing answer - what is generated for?  Why does  setOverridenSet() not actually set the passed value?  @marandus answer is the correct answer.

Comment: @RodneyP.Barbati I removed generated, no idea why that was in. setOverriddenSet() doesn't set the passed value because that's what op asked for.